# Set 8th bit if all lower 7 bits are set without branching

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, branchless

I am trying to set the highest bit in a byte value only when all lower 7 bits are set without introducing branching.

for example, given the following inputs:

```
input: 0b_0010_1100 -> return same value
input: 0b_0101_0101 -> return same value
input: 0b_0111_1111 -> all bits set except MSB, return 0xff
input: 0b_1010_1100 -> MSB is already set, return same value
```

This only needs to work for values of 8-bit size.

I tried a few attempts using `popcount` but that didn't work for all input.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that only the lower 7 bits can be set in the input? If so @Brendan's solution is correct.

Comment: Since you have accepted an answer that only works conditionally—only if bit 8 is known to be clear—you should edit the question to state that this condition is a premise of the problem. Stack Overflow questions and answers are supposed to be a durable repository to serve other people in the future. So it is not just answering your question that is at issue but presenting a problem clearly so that it and the answer(s) are useful to other people in the future.

Comment: `input: 0b_0111_1111 -> all bits set except the highest one, return 0xff` it is acontraversion. `all bits set except the highest one` means that the highest bit must not be set

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hmm.. Have you actually tested it? Because from what I can see it works regardless whether bit 8 is set or clear.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it stops working when input is larger than a byte so I have edited my question to mention that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
return x | ((x+1) & 0x80);
```

Comment: Or `return x | (((x & 0x7F)+1) & 0x80);` if other bits can be set as well.

Comment: @fpiette: Your version has the same end result as mine; even when `x` is larger than 8 bits (and even if `x` is something like `UINT_MAX` where the `x+1` overflows and wraps around).

Comment: I don't think this works in case x already has MSB set.

Comment: @Lundin: If MSB is already set, then `x | (anything & MSB)` is guaranteed to do absolutely nothing regardless of what `anything` is.

Comment: Yeah but I mean if MSB should _only_ be set when the other 7 bits are all ones, then this code doesn't do that.